# Class imbalance inherent to GANs?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Is the class imbalance problem inherent to GANs? In a GAN, there are 2 networks working against each other, one is a classifier and the adversary is trying to fool the classifier by generating fake images. All of the generated images from the GAN will be fakes, so if the algorithm is run for long enough, there has to be a class imbalance, right?

Answer (score 0):

Not right, but you have some basic concepts correct.

The classifier trains with real images as well.  It's goal is to accurately discriminate between these real images and the fakes from the generator.

The adversary's goal is to generate images that will fool the classifier.

The model builder (i.e. you) chooses the balance between real and fake images in each iteration.  This supports experiments to determine the most effective ratio.

True, the real images have a fixed population, and the generated images are effectively infinite.  However, the idea of "class imbalance" doesn't apply as well here: after each iteration, the old fake images are replaced by new ones.  The old images were useful for earlier training, but are not used after that single exposure to the classifier.

Comment: If you keep reusing the real images, they don't introduce new information, so why would you keep reusing them in later iterations?

Comment: For the same reason we reuse them in any other training scenario.  Training is a process of continued refinement, not a closed-form solution.  We revisit each of the inputs until the model converges.